# creating markers in Javascript based on ranges

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know my syntax is incorrect here but I can't seem to figure out the correct syntax to create different colored markers based on a range.  This is what I have now and all of my markers show up green (blank_g.png)

```
  function createMarker(point,info,map,mag) {

        var colorMarker = "blank_g.png"  //for mag < 4 

        if (mag >= 4.0 && mag < 5.0) {
        colorMarker = "blank_b.png";
        }
        else if (mag >= 5.0 && mag < 6.0) {
        colorMarker = "blank_p.png";
        }
        else if (mag >= 6.0 && mag < 7.0) {
        colorMarker = "blank_y.png";
        }
        else if (mag >= 7.0 && mag < 8.0) {
        colorMarker = "blank_o.png";
        }
        else if (mag >= 8.0) {
        colorMarker = "blank_r.png";
        }
```

Comment: where/how do you create the markers, how do you call this function?

Comment: What are the values provided to the createMarker function for `mag`?  Are they all less than 4.0? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no there are some that are between 4 and 5. The script is pulling the data from here: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/#%7B%22feed%22%3A%221day_m25%22%2C%22search%22%3Anull%2C%22sort%22%3A%22newest%22%2C%22basemap%22%3A%22grayscale%22%2C%22autoUpdate%22%3Atrue%2C%22restrictListToMap%22%3Atrue%2C%22timeZone%22%3A%22local%22%2C%22mapposition%22%3A%5B%5B-44.84029065139799%2C-219.0234375%5D%2C%5B81.2550322990594%2C-25.3125%5D%5D%2C%22overlays%22%3A%7B%22plates%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22viewModes%22%3A%7B%22map%22%3Atrue%2C%22list%22%3Atrue%2C%22settings%22%3Atrue%2C%22help%22%3Afalse%7D%7D

Comment: I got yelled at the last time I put my whole code here.  But nevermind...I just figured out that I forgot to add "mag" to the createmarker function at the bottom.  It's amazing how you see things after walking away from it for awhile

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateMarker (point, info, map, mag)
{
    // Recommended: Check value of mag for range

    var imageNames =
    [
        "blank_g.png",
        "blank_g.png",
        "blank_g.png",
        "blank_g.png",
        "blank_b.png",
        "blank_p.png",
        "blank_y.png",
        "blank_o.png",
        "blank_r.png",
    ];

    var imageIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(Math.floor(mag), imageNames.length - 1));
    var imgBaseUrl = "/images/"; // Or whatever your path is.
    var imgSrc = imageBaseUrl + imageNames[imageIndex];

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    ({
        icon: MarkerIconUrl(imgSrc),
        map: map,
        position: point,
        title: info
    });

    return marker;
}

function MarkerIconUrl (imgSrc)
{
    return new google.maps.MarkerImage(imgSrc);
}

function MarkerIconUrlByRgb (color)
{
    return new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + color);
}
```